Continuity of $f(x,y)=[x^2+y^2]\frac{x^2y^2}{x^4+y^4}$ on Y-axis
My question is an extension of this question 
For reference the question was

For $t\in \mathbb R$, let $[t]$ denote the greatest integer less than or equal to t. Let $D=\left\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2:x^2+y^2<4\right\}$. 
Let $f:D\to\mathbb R$ and $g:D\to \mathbb R$ be defined by $f(0,0)=g(0,0)=0$ and $$f(x,y)=[x^2+y^2]\frac{x^2y^2}{x^4+y^4}$$ and $$g(x,y)=[y^2]\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}$$ for $(x,y)\neq(0,0)$. Let E be the set of points of D at which both f and g are discontinuous. Find the number of elements in the set E.

The accepted answer pointed to 18 points, of which 6 lie on the $Y$ - axis, which are
$(0,\pm 1),(0,\pm \sqrt2),(0,\pm \sqrt3)$.
It can be seen that $f(0,a) = g(0,a) = 0,\,\,a\in \mathbb (-4,4)$. I think $f,g$ are continuous on the Y-axis.
Checking continuity on $(0,1)$
$$|f(x,y) - f(0,1)|= |f(x,y)|$$
$$|f(x,y)|=\begin{cases}\left|\frac{x^2y^2}{x^4+y^4}\right|,& 1\le x^2 + y^2 \lt 2\\ 0,& x^2 + y^2 \lt 1.\end{cases}$$
$\because \frac{x^2y^2}{x^4+y^4}$ is continuous on $0 \lt x^2 + y^2 \lt 2$.
$\therefore$ For a given $\epsilon \gt 0$ we can find $\delta > 0$ s.t.
$$ \left|\frac{x^2y^2}{x^4+y^4}\right| < \epsilon,\,\,\,d((0,1),(x,y)) \lt \delta $$
Using this fact we can bound $f(x,y)$ by any given $\epsilon$ and prove that f is continuous on $(0,1)$. This can be extended to all the remaining points on the Y-axis.
I wanted to check if my assertion/assumption about $f\, \& \,g$ being continuous on the Y-axis  is correct or if I'm missing something?

@Paul Sinclair to access continuity at (0,1), I consider a disc around it, some of the points in that disk are such that $x^2+y^2 < 1$ for these points $f(x,y)= 0$
and others have $2>x^2+y^2 >1 $ so here $f(x,y) = \frac{x^2y^2}{x^4+y^4}$, as $[x^2+y^2] =1 $ for these points.

@PaulSinclair Post that I've invoked the fact that for any given $\epsilon > 0$ i can find a find disk around (0,1) let's call it $B$ such that
$$1.)2>x^2+y^2>0$$
$$2.)|\frac{x^2y^2}{x^4+y^4}| < \epsilon $$
From here we can easily bound $$|f(x,y) - f(0,1)|<\epsilon$$, as $f(x,y)$ is either $0$ or $ \frac{x^2y^2}{x^4+y^4}$ inside the disc B.

Sorry. I read too lightly and mis-interpreted your post. You are correct. We have $$|f(x,y)| < 32\frac {x^2y^2}{x^4 + y^4}$$ everywhere in $D$, and since $\frac {x^2y^2}{x^4 + y^4} \to 0$ as $x\to 0$ (and $y$ stays away from $0$(), so must $f$, which makes $f$ continuous on the $y$-axis. And similarly for $g$. While $f$ and $g$ are generally discontinuous along the circles and lines as indicated in the other post, the size of those discontinuities goes to $0$ as you approach the $y$-axis, making $f$ and $g$ continuous along it.
